# Qualys ID mapping to Common vulnerability exposure

Tags: security

Is it possible to map every QualysGuard vulnerability ID to common vulnerability expousre ID (CVE) or vice versa ?

Answer (score 1):

QualysGuard already map the QID with CVEs whenever possible.
if you have a QualysGuard account with the API module switched on and access to the knowledge base API, then you can download the full knowledge base in XML and extract the CVE information following this XPath:
/KNOWLEDGE_BASE_VULN_LIST_OUTPUT/RESPONSE/VULN_LIST/VULN/CVE_LIST/CVE/

More information can be found here:
https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-2976

You'll find a script that does more than you requested. It creates CSV file and "kb_v2-cve.csv"provides the mapping.